# New to C, having some trouble with compiling

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm getting some errors when I compile a couple short C programs, and I'm very lost as to what is going on:

First one gives these errors:

> Q3.c: In function âsortâ:
>
> Q3.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function âq_sortâ
>
> Q3.c: At top level:
>
> Q3.c:14: warning: conflicting types for âq_sortâ
>
> Q3.c:11: note: previous implicit declaration of âq_sortâ was here
>
> Q3.c: In function âmainâ:
>
> Q3.c:52: warning: implicit declaration of function âmallocâ
>
> Q3.c:52: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âmallocâ
>
> Q3.c:56: warning: implicit declaration of function ârandâ

Relevent parts of code:

```
void sort(int* number, int n){
 /*Sort the given array number , of length n*/
 q_sort(number, 0, (n - 1));
}

void q_sort(int* numbers, int left, int right)
{
  int pivot, l_hold, r_hold;

  l_hold = left;
  r_hold = right;
  pivot = numbers[left];
  while (left < right)
  {
    while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
      right--;
    if (left != right)
    {
      numbers[left] = numbers[right];
      left++;
    }
    while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
      left++;
    if (left != right)
    {
      numbers[right] = numbers[left];
      right--;
    }
  }
  numbers[left] = pivot;
  pivot = left;
  left = l_hold;
  right = r_hold;
  if (left < pivot)
    q_sort(numbers, left, pivot-1);
  if (right > pivot)
    q_sort(numbers, pivot+1, right); 
}
```

Since my other problem programs all use the same sort method, and give the same errors, fixing this will fix all.

EDIT: One additional problem.  I get this error on another program

> Q5.c: In function âstickyâ:
>
> Q5.c:29: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>
> Q5.c:29: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior

in this part of the code:

```
void sticky(char* word){
     int i = 0;
     /*Convert to sticky caps*/
     while (word[i] !="\0"){    // line 29
          if (i%2 == 0)
                word[i] = toUpperCase(word[i]);
          else
                word[i] = toLowerCase(word[i]);
          i++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swap the definition of the two functions... In C you must first declare (or define) a function and only after you can use it.

For the second issue: you must use single quotes to define a character.

Comment: That fixed that issue, thank you.  Do you have any insight into the second issue (I edited it in because I found it right after I hit submit)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed that one as well.  Trying to learn C very quickly makes little issues like this very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also define them at the beginning of the .c file (it can be after your libraries), then you can use them anywhere in any order.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int*, int n);
void q_sort(int*, int, int);

...
...
/* Any code */

/* Your sort function */
/* Your q_sort function */

/* Any code*/
```

Comment: C std libraries should included with <> instead of "": `#include <file>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the function `sticky()` is that you are comparing a `char` to a `char*` when you do `(word[i] != "\0")`.

"\0" is not the character `\0`, its a pointer to a string containing the character `\0`. To fix this, use `(word[i] != '\0')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much I am going to add apart from what is said in above couple of answers. Just a C basic when you write a function and use it in a file.

When you use/cal a function like 'qsort' you should always declare it before/above it is called from anywhere in your program. So rule is that your program should know the 'prototype of the function you are calling. In this case it it:

void q_sort(int* numbers, int left, int right);

This prototype is usually mentioned at the top of your program file after you #include all necessary '.h' files and define all your macros.

OR else you can also opt for defining the function (full function body) itself at the top before you call them.

Else compiler will crib when it does not find the declaration.